# Replacing characters in a word from the specified position to the end in a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, str-replace

I need to print output like this:
"jav-" for 'java'
"pyt---" for 'python'
"kot---" for 'kotlin'
"jav-------" for 'javascript'

For 'python' and 'kotlin' it prints as expected, but for 'java' or 'javascript' it prints "j-v-" and "j-v------".

```
word = ['python', 'java', 'kotlin', 'javascript']
import random
x = random.choice(word)
print("old value of X >", x)
lamai = len(x)
change = 3
symbol = "-"
while lamai > change:
    y = x.replace(x[change], symbol)
    x = y
    change = change + 1
    print("this is y", y)
```

[image: visualisation of code]

Comment: `x[:3] + '-' * (len(x) - 3)`

Comment: thank you for your quick response. 
May I know, "why is this happening only with specific words like java, javascript, geneva, salad, silicon (any word which index [2] and index [3] or [4] are same.

Comment: Because you didn't tell it to replace the third character with a `-`.  You told it to replace all matching characters.  So, for 'java', you replaced all of the a's with -'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original code `str.replace` replaced provided characters with `-`. You received `j-v-`, because you replaced `a` with `-`. In `x.replace(x[change], symbol)`, the part `x[change]` only tells the position where your character (in this case `a`) is located. Then `replace` just replaces every occurrence of `a` with `-`.

Reworking your code:

```
word = ['python', 'java', 'kotlin', 'javascript']
import random
x = random.choice(word)
print("old value of X >", x)
lamai = len(x)
change = 3
symbol = "-"
while lamai > change:
    y = x[:change] + symbol + x[change+1:]
    x = y
    change = change + 1
    print("this is y", y)
```